# Don't understand why initial check doesn't prevent "unsupported operand type(s) for +" from occurring

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I encountered the following error for my Quicksort implementation. I've noticed most recursive algorithms state the `length == 1` check at the front. But why doesn't it work in this case?

```
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array)==1:
        return array
    elif len(array)>1:
        less=[]
        equal=[]
        greater=[]
        pivot=array[0]
        for x in array:
            if x<pivot:
                less.append(x)
            if x==pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            if x>pivot:
                greater.append(x)
            array=quicksort(less)+equal+quicksort(greater)
        return array

lst=[7,2,6,4,5,1,3,8]
quicksort(lst)
```

The error is about `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'`. I don't understand where the `NoneType` comes from. I thought it should at least be an empty list [].

Reversing the order of the `length==1` and `length>1` cases fixed the problem, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Do some basic debugging like printing the array at the top of the function. You will find that a length of zero is possible which means it's not handled by either branch (neither == 1 nor >  1). When that happens, what does your function return?

Comment: Also, you probably didn't mean to have the line `arr=quicksort...` inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that an empty list [] can be returned but []+[]+[] returns no error. So I am not sure where the error comes from. Looking for an intuitive explanation.

Comment: arr=quicksort... is not the problem. return quicksort(less)+equal+... gives the same error.

Comment: Intuitively `quicksort(less)` returns `None` when `less` or `greater` is  empty because you don't explicitly return anything in that case. Test this with `quicksort([])`. You then try to concat that `None` to the return value which causes the error you see. `arr=quicksort` is not causing this to fail...it is causing you to call the recursive function *many* more times that needed for no reason. You only need to do this *once* after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your `if-elif` statement in `quicksort`.

Essentially, when you first run `quicksort` with `lst`, if you add this code right before `array=quicksort(less)+equal+quicksort(greater)`:

```
print(less)
print(equal)
print(greater)
```

You can see that both `less` and `greater` are empty lists.

When you pass them recursively as values to `quicksort`, their length, as empty lists, will be 0. Your `if-elif` statement *only* covers the cases of the array's length being exactly 1 or greater than 1. Because the length is 0, neither block will execute, so your function will default to returning `None`.

Thus, this line:

```
array=quicksort(less)+equal+quicksort(greater)
```

is attempting to do this:

```
array=None+[7]+None
```

which causes your error.